# Display deleted offline databases again in SMSS or delete their data files via SMSS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I've dropped some offline databases through SMSS to free space. But I've discovered that, when I drop an offline database, its disk files are not deleted.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178613.aspx

> Dropping a database deletes the database from an instance of SQL Server and deletes the physical disk files used by the database. If the database or any one of its files is offline when it is dropped, the disk files are not deleted. These files can be deleted manually by using Windows Explorer. To remove a database from the current server without deleting the files from the file system, use sp_detach_db.

Since I don't have direct access to the server, is there a way of showing these databases again in SMSS or deleting their disk files via SMSS?

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using DROP DATABASE Database_Name

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Execute the following statements

```
USE master
GO

ALTER DATABASE DataBase_Name
SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO

DROP DATABASE DataBase_Name
GO
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. I cannot use the database in queries because it is already dropped. I just need to delete the physical files or make the database available again in SMSS. Thanks!